# Graph and nodes how to determine the connection weight and impact

Tags: networking, graph, graph-theory

I am having a network of objects that are connected each other. 
Each object as usual can have classes and structures, etc.
I am giving you an example because it is difficult to explained other wise.

A structure propagates from one object to the another.For example object-1 can be an FTP server that sends a specific file with specific structure to a neighbor node, object-2. This connection e.g. is related with a protocol (FTP) and a specific file structure.

Among other what I am trying to determine are the following:
1. How can I measure the weight of this connection, I mean what could be the characteristics that I have to choose and use? How can I measure them?

1. In the case where nodes are connected to other nodes any change of a property, eg. a file structure impacts the operation of the next node that is connected. In which way I can can determine the diffusion of a change within a network and the impact per node?

Thanks a lot

George